# semantic UI responsive utilities workaround

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, semantic-ui

I'm a semantic-ui newbie, usually I use bootstrap 3.0 and i really like the "visible-xs" feature, someone have a workaround for this on semantic-ui ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's just

```
.visible-xs { display: none !important; }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .visible-xs { display: block !important; }
}
```

Just add it somewhere to the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use container's visibility for that: 
http://semantic-ui.com/elements/container.html#/introduction

But be carefully, they only works for containers not individual elements.

If you want to use it like Bootstrap on particular elements, you can use some of this snippets:

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1114

And this is actually the discussion to allow that support on semantic ;)